# Finite and infinite sets, cardinality question

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Suppose there are infinite sets $A$, $B$ and $C$ such that $$|A| = |B| = |C| = |\mathbb{N}|\\ |D| = |\mathbb{R}|$$ and the finite set $E$

Give an example for the following (using the sets above). In case it's not possible, show why.

1. $(A \setminus D = B) \wedge (A \cap D = C)$
2. $\mathcal P(E) \setminus A = B $
3. $|D| = |E|^{|A|}$

This is an exam type of exercise i couldn't answer it, if there is a soul that can help, I'll appreciate it.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft That is correct, fixed it, thanks :)

Comment: @DonAntonio Would it make sense if instead of $|D| = |\mathbb{R}|$ was $|D| = |\mathbb{Z}|$ ?

Comment: Diego, do you know that $|\Bbb Z|=|\Bbb N|$?

Comment: @DiegoZacarias , I think you're taking "set difference" within some given, fixed universal set, and not one wrt the other one. It's fine.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Sorry, you are correct, they are equivalent!

Comment: I am sorry, but how can be $\mathcal P(E) \setminus A = B$? $\mathcal P(E)$ is finite but $B$ is infinite.

Comment: @Kunnysan There was a remark at the end of the exercise i forgot to add here, just edited my question, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some hints:

1. Start with the case of $D'\cap A=\varnothing$, and find a suitable subset $C$. For example $D'$ can be the irrational numbers, $A$ the rational numbers, and $C$ the natural numbers.
2. This is impossible $B$ is infinite but $E$ is finite. The power set of a finite set is finite, and $\mathcal P(E)\setminus A$ is a subset of $\mathcal P(E)$.
3. Remember that $\Bbb R$ and $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$ are equipotent.

Comment: You forgot to mention that $|\mathbb{N}|=|\mathbb{R}|$, as proved [on the arXiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/0809.4144), viXra's competitor.

Comment: @julien: What's sad is that this paper was posted on 2008. Not in 1998, when cranks roamed freely in the arXiv...

Comment: I tried something: I wrote to the arXiv admins to draw their attention to that paper, suggesting its removal, and recalling that it is well established, in particular, that $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{N}$ are not equipotent. Here is the answer: "Thank you for your valuable feedback.  Our moderators reviewed the submission five years ago and determined the paper was appropriate for math.GM (General Mathematics) at that time."

Comment: @julien: Well, you can't undo the clock. Oh well.